# Differentiate programmatically between LinkedList and List

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I want to know difference between `List` and `LinkedList` programmatically. Can any one help me?

```
List list=new LinkedList();
```

Comment: You should read some topics on Data Structures.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html

Comment: BTW - the title *"differentiate programatically between Linkedlist and list alongside using a hash map"* makes about as much sense to me as if it had read *"differentiate programatically between Linkedlist and list alongside using a toad the wet sprocket"*.  Whatever does hash map have to do with it?

Comment: One small but important note: don't use raw types. In your case, it should be `List<T> list = new LinkedList<>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **List**: The List extends the `Collection` interface. A `List` is a collection with an ordered sequence of elements and may contain duplicates. `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` and
  `Vector` are implementations of a List interface. (i.e. an **index based**)
- **LinkedList** doesn't allocate memory to the items before the items are added to the list. 
  Each item in a `LinkedList` holds a pointer to the next in the list.`LinkedList` is implementation of a `List` interface.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`List` is the `interface` and `LinkedList` is a `subclass` of `List` which implements the methods (plus some other utility methods) of List interface.

And `HashMap` is a totally different type of `datastructure` implementing `Map` which stores key value pairs.

So don't be confused about `List`, `LinkedList`, `HashMap` ... better ready the structures of these.

Answer (score 0):

List is an interface, LinkedList is a Concrete Class which implements  the List interface. So, you can create an object of LinkedList (concrete class) but not List (interface). Every LinkedList is also a List, so you can do

```
List list=new LinkedList();
```

Linked List declaration :

```
public class java.util.LinkedList extends java.util.AbstractSequentialList implements java.util.List, java.util.Deque, java.lang.Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedList` is a particular type of data structure, where `List` is implemented using `LinkedList`. You can create a List Interface implementing anyway you like even using array (though usually implemented using LinkedList). Main thing is you just provide some functionality with the interface. But `LinkedList` itself is universal in nature.